# How to solve error in domain.yml while training rasa

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

While running rasa train , I get an error which automatially takes an empty domain.yml instead of the .yml file that I want to choose . The error shows that there is a presence of duplicate keys.

> C:\Users\nitik\rasabot>rasa train
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py:351:
>   UserWarning: Loading domain from 'domain.yml' failed. Using empty
>   domain. Error: 'The provided yaml file contains a duplicated key:
>   'while constructing a mapping   in "", line 25, column
>   3 found duplicate key "-text" with value "Hi.My name is medicare
>   locator. How can I help you today ?" (original value: "Hello. I am a
>   medicare locator. I can help you find nearest hospital. How can I help
>   ?")   in "", line 43, column 3
>
> To suppress this check see:
>       http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys
>
> Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
>   by default when using the new API. '. You can use
>   http://www.yamllint.com/ to validate the yaml syntax of your file.'
>   Training NLU model... 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Training data stats:
>           - intent examples: 56 (9 distinct intents)
>           - Found intents: 'affirm', 'search_provider', 'greet', 'goodbye', 'mood_great', 'inform', 'bot_challenge', 'deny',
>   'mood_unhappy'
>           - Number of response examples: 0 (0 distinct response)
>           - entity examples: 13 (2 distinct entities)
>           - found entities: 'facility_type', 'location'
>
> 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train
>   component WhitespaceTokenizer 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component. 2020-04-01 01:32:49
>   INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component RegexFeaturizer
>   2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training
>   component. 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to
>   train component LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component. 2020-04-01 01:32:49
>   INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component
>   CountVectorsFeaturizer 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  -
>   Finished training component. 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component CountVectorsFeaturizer
>   2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training
>   component. 2020-04-01 01:32:49 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to
>   train component DIETClassifier 2020-04-01 01:32:49.711102: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to
>   cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303) Epochs:
>   100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100
>   [00:52<00:00,  2.52it/s, t_loss=1.835, i_loss=0.199, e_loss=0.026,
>   i_acc=1.000, e_f1=0.938] 2020-04-02 22:40:45 INFO
>   rasa.utils.tensorflow.models  - Finished training. 2020-04-02 22:40:46
>   INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Finished training component. 2020-04-02
>   22:40:46 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component
>   EntitySynonymMapper 2020-04-02 22:40:46 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  -
>   Finished training component. 2020-04-02 22:40:46 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.model  - Starting to train component ResponseSelector
>   2020-04-02 22:40:46 INFO     rasa.nlu.selectors.response_selector  -
>   Retrieval intent parameter was left to its default value. This
>   response selector will be trained on training examples combining all
>   retrieval intents. 2020-04-02 22:40:46 INFO     rasa.nlu.model  -
>   Finished training component. 2020-04-02 22:40:55 INFO
>   rasa.nlu.model  - Successfully saved model into
>   'C:\Users\nitik\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy9i6wqpt\nlu' NLU model training
>   completed.
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py:351:
>   UserWarning: Loading domain from 'domain.yml' failed. Using empty
>   domain. Error: 'The provided yaml file contains a duplicated key:
>   'while constructing a mapping   in "", line 25, column
>   3 found duplicate key "-text" with value "Hi.My name is medicare
>   locator. How can I help you today ?" (original value: "Hello. I am a
>   medicare locator. I can help you find nearest hospital. How can I help
>   ?")   in "", line 43, column 3
>
> To suppress this check see:
>       http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys
>
> Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
>   by default when using the new API. '. You can use
>   http://www.yamllint.com/ to validate the yaml syntax of your file.'
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 2. Please, make sure
>   that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'search_provider' on line 4. Please,
>   make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'thanks' on line 7. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 11. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'search_provider' on line 13.
>   Please, make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'inform' on line 15. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'thanks' on line 18. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 22. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'mood_great' on line 24. Please,
>   make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 28. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'mood_unhappy' on line 30. Please,
>   make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'affirm' on line 33. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 37. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'mood_unhappy' on line 39. Please,
>   make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'deny' on line 42. Please, make sure
>   that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'goodbye' on line 46. Please, make
>   sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,
>   c:\users\nitik\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\training\dsl.py:422:
>   UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'bot_challenge' on line 50. Please,
>   make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.
>   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS, Your Rasa model is trained and saved at
>   'C:\Users\nitik\rasabot\models\nlu-20200402-224056.tar.gz'. Core
>   training was skipped because no valid domain file was found. Only an
>   nlu-model was created.Please specify a valid domain using '--domain'
>   argument or check if the provided domain file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain.yml is not a valid YAML file, so Rasa cannot use it and starts instead with an empty file.

Go to http://www.yamllint.com/ and paste the content of your domain.yml, you can easily validate it and find the error/inconsistency (sometimes it is just indentation, but it seems you have some duplication reading error trace).